# Canvas DrawLine Is Invisible

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to draw a single line in Android using canvas

**My class :**

```
public class LineDrawer extends View {

    public LineDrawer(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        float left = 20;
        float top = 20;
        float right = 50;
        float bottom = 100;

        canvas.drawLine(left, top, right, bottom, paint);

    }
}
```

**My Main Activity :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       LineDrawer lineDrawer = new  LineDrawer(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_Main);
    }
}
```

I cannot find where is the problem , I try all the solutions in the internet but nothing happen , still a blank activity..

Should I import some code ?

Comment: `setContentView(lineDrawer)`

Comment: what if i want to use the xml file for this activity ?

Comment: so use `setContentView(R.layout.activity_Main)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lineDrawer` is created but not added anywhere. Just creating a view is not enough, you need to add it to the current displayed views to be taken into account and drawn. You have two options:

- Add it to your XML layout. You will have to add the following constructor to your custom view.

  `public LineDrawer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
      super(context, attrs);
  }`
- Use addView(). Anyway, given how simple is your example, I'll use first (common) method.

As an additional comment, the `Paint paint` object should be created on view initialization, as is a costly operation. See in the [original documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html#createobject) for more information about this.

Comment: when an instance are created from a class inheritance from a View , when the compiler try to draw the view it will go tho the method onDraw() , isn't that right?

Comment: Just creating a class is not enough, you need to add it to the current displayed views to be taken into account and drawn. Also, just for the sake of correctness, the compiler doesn't draw anything, is the OS. I've edited the answer.

Comment: thank you , but can you tell me how to add this line to my View? addContentView takes two parameters context and LayoutParms

Comment: As I said, the easiest way would be directly on your activity_Main layout. You should find it in res/layout/activity_Main in your project structure. Open it and copy and paste the XML to your question. You have to put a tag similar to `<your.package.LineDrawer android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />` (notice tag it is closed with a / at the end).